# Proving by induction that $ (1+i)^{2n+1} = a_n +ib_n $ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are $\pm 2^n$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

I need to prove by induction that $ (1+i)^{2n+1} = a_n +ib_n $ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are $\pm 2^n$
For that I assume that $ (1+i)^{2n+1} = a_n +ib_n $ is true after having shown that it is true for $n=0$. Then I want to show that $ (1+i)^{2(n+1)+1} = (1+i)^{2n+3} = a_n +ib_n $ is also true, so for that I have to multiply $ (1+i)^{2n+1} $ by $ (1+i)^{2} $, but $ (1+i)^{2} $ is false? So how can i proceed ? Where did I make a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: What do you mean by $(1 + i)^2$ is false? I think you are on the right track. Note that $(1 + i)^2 = 1 + 2i - 1 = 2i$. The result should follow almost directly from here.

Comment: to use $(1+i)^2$, i need to show that it is true using $(1+i)^{2n+1}$ right ? But i can't obtain a power of 2 using this formula?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your confusion. For the proof, you first need to show for $n= 0$ (which you have done). Now assume it holds for $n$, that is, $(1 + i)^{2n+1} = a_n + i b_n$ for $a_n, b_n = \pm 2^n$. Now you need to show that  $(1 + i)^{2n+3} = a_{n+1} + i b_{n+1}$ for $a_{n+1}, b_{n+1} = \pm 2^{n+1}$. As you noted, $(1 + i)^{2n + 3} = (1 + i)^{2n + 1}(1 + i)^2 = (a_n + i b_n) (2i)$ with $a_n, b_n = \pm 2^n$. Can you complete the rest? Let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: @sudeep5221 You should consider posting an answer based on your comments.

Comment: $(a_n+ib_n)(2i) = 2^{n+1}i+i^2{2n+1} = 2^{n+1}i - 2^{n+1}$ and the proof is done ? I thought that in order to use $(1+i)^2$ $i$ had to be in the first step of the proof instead of initializing it with $n=0$

Comment: Yes the proof is indeed done! Why does $i$ need to be in the first step of the proof?

Comment: I have no idea, I think all the proof by induction I've done till now involved using what was done in the initialization. I'll relearn it I think haha. Thanks for the help!